# Getting the position of an AnchorPane child in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Let's say I have:

```
AnchorPane anchorpane = new AnchorPane();
Anchorpane.setTopAnchor(node, randomNumber());
Anchorpane.setLeftAnchor(node, randomNumber());
```

Is there a way to get the **position** of anchorpane's node *without* explicitly knowing the values of `randomNumber()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the values by calling the getter methods and passing the `node` to it.

```
AnchorPane.getTopAnchor(node);
Anchorpane.getLeftAnchor(node);
```